# How to create an asio socket with an existing fd and callback into custom code rather than read from it when data is available

Tags: c++, asio

I have a C++ application where I'm using a 3rd Party api. As part of that api they will handle the socket connections etc, however, they have a mode where I can select / poll on the fd and then call into the api read from the socket, decode the data and dispatch to the proper handlers; this way we can control the thread where the dispatch code runs. Now I also have extensive use of asio for my networking and I would like to handle this with that. In fact, I desire the api's dispatch code to run on in the asio thread. So, I would like an asio socket that takes the existing fd and then makes a call to what I want when there is data on the fd. This seems pretty straight forward but I can't find it in the docs / examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found what I needed, asio::posix::stream_descriptor. I can assign it the socket handle (fd) and then call async_wait and asio will notify me when there is data to be read:

```
    descriptor_.assign(connection_.get_socket_handle());
    descriptor_.async_wait(asio::posix::stream_descriptor::wait_read, [this] (const std::error_code& error) { this->handle_data(error); });
```

Answer (score 1):

For sure this depends on what asio framework your are on.

In [my libevent-based framework](https://github.com/grizzlybears/tevpp)  , I implement the operation like this

```cpp
void BaseConnection::take_socket(evutil_socket_t fd, short event_mask, int options)
{
    this->bev = bufferevent_socket_new( get_event_base(), fd, options);
    if (!this->bev) {
        throw SimpleException("Error constructing bufferevent on fd #%d", fd);
    }

    bufferevent_setcb(bev, trampoline_readable, trampoline_writable , trampoline_event , (void*) this);
    bufferevent_enable(bev, event_mask);
}
```

After `take_socket` gets called, `fd` would be taken by a `buffered event` (this->bev)，
and when income data available, `trampoline_readable` will be called.

If you are on boost::asio, though I am not familiar on it, you may have interest on `basic_stream_socket::assign`.

Good luck:)